# SDB device unauthorized

Tags: tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

Hi So I have recently been developing apps for my Samsung Galaxy smartwatch.
Initially when I connected to it, it asked for permission. But a while ago I reset my device (To enable samsung pay). I then precoded to restore a backup.

Now when I try to connect my watch to my computer with sdb, I get the error message

```
C:\tizen-studio\tools>sdb connect 192.168.137.41:26101
connecting to 192.168.137.41:26101 ... device unauthorized. Please approve on your device.
```

But nothing shows up on my device.

Then when I run that command again I get the message

```
C:\tizen-studio\tools>sdb connect 192.168.137.41:26101
192.168.137.41:26101 is already connected
```

So I then try to get shell access like I have been able to do in the past, then I get this error:

```
C:\tizen-studio\tools>sdb shell
device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

But again, I have no dialog that shows up on my watch.

So right now, I am not able to develop any more apps for my watch as it wont let me connect to it anymore.

To fix this problem on android devices you normally just need to Revoke USB DEBUGGING Authorization. But I cant find this option on Tizen OS.

What can I do to allow my watch to connect to my computer again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix was to go into `C:\Users\{USER}\.tizen` and ether delete that folder or delete the items in it. This changes your key to a new one which make the watch prompt you to accept the new key

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. However I think it's worth noting that I had to run sdb kill-server after deleting the key, before it would start working again.

Comment: This seems to have made a difference, but instead of getting the unauthorized issue, I know get
`failed to connect to 192.168.1.37:26101`
when connecting, and when listing devices, I get
`192.168.1.37:26101      offline         <unknown>`.
It works fine on my other device, though.  I've tried restarting the server, but no luck either.

Comment: If you're stuck, you might have to run `sdb.exe kill-server`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer above but did not succeed.

My device also displayed unauthorized:

```
> sdb.exe devices
List of devices attached
192.168.1.9:26101       unauthorized    <unknown>
```

When starting a shell with

```
> sdb.exe shell
```

the watch asked me to confirm the debugging connection.

With that I was able to use the shell and the watch was finally connected.